# Bad response.content on request.post

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

> Using python 3.7

I'm trying to build a small script that will post data using an api however I'm not able to get the response.content properly because there's some strange characters coming out.

```
import requests
files = {
    'content': (None, 'text'),
}
response = requests.post('http://localhost/api/v2', files=files)
print (response.content)
```

> Outputs: b'http://localhost/1NSZAOWE\n'

I tried erasing characters doing

```
txt = (response.content)
print (txt[1:])
```

> Outputs: b'ttp://localhost/2LSALWE\n'

Can someone help me finding out a way to avoid getting those odd characters in the url that comes out as response.content?

Answer (score 1):

`response.content`  is returning byte string so you have to convert it to string(utf-8) and use `strip()` to remove tailing newline

```
response.content.decode('utf-8').strip()
```

check [Convert bytes to a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/606191/convert-bytes-to-a-string#606199)

Comment: Found out with @Marcin comment, thanks for the answer, really new to python syntax but I get the references